# Flex4, centering and resizing a image inside a group container

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm looking for the best way to get a flex 4 image object to resize and horizontally center whenever its parent container (a custom component based on group) resizes.  I cannot set horizontalCenter="0" to accomplish the image centering because I use a move transition to "slide" the image in and out of view.

I'm externally setting the image source in the component.  Here is a simplified example of my component code that only addresses  resizing the image.

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[                   
            public function assignImage(imgUrl:String):void
            {
                imgA.source = imgUrl;
                imgA.visible = true;
            }

            override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number,h:Number):void
            {
                imgA.width = w;
                imgA.height = h;
                super.updateDisplayList(w,h);           
            }        
        ]]>

    </fx:Script>         

    <s:Image id="imgA" visible="false" top="0" maintainAspectRatio="true"  />        
</s:Group>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated -- I'm also open to an alternate method of resizing the image if it makes more sense.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rhtx was on the right track, but there is no easy way to center the image control with his solution.  After some testing I came up with the following to solve this problem.  I hope it saves you all some time.

Here is the code for the custom component based on a group that contains the image control.

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo" 
         creationComplete="group1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" 
         > 

    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[                    
            public function assignImage(imgUrl:String):void 
            { 
                imgA.source = imgUrl; 
                imgA.visible = true; 
            } 

           protected function group1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                this.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, SinglePageViewer_resizeHandler); 
            }    

            protected function group1_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
            {                           
                updateImageDimensionsAndPosition(this.width, this.height);
            }           

            private function updateImageDimensionsAndPosition(w:Number, h:Number):void 
            { 
                var aspect:Number = imgA.width / imgA.height;    
                var containerAspect:Number = w / h;

                if ( isNaN(aspect) == false )
                {                       
                    if (aspect <= containerAspect)  
                    { 
                        imgA.height = h; 
                        imgA.width = aspect * imgA.height;                  
                    } 
                    else  
                    { 
                        imgA.width = w; 
                        imgA.height = imgA.width / aspect; 
                    } 

                    // If you want to horizontally center the image, uncomment the following 
                    /*
                    var oldX:Number = imgA.x;                           
                    var newX:Number = w/2 - imgA.width/2; 
                    if ( (oldX != newX) && (newX > 0) )
                    {
                        imgA.x = newX;
                    }
                    */                  
                }            
            } 
        ]]>  
    </fx:Script>          

    <s:Image id="imgA" visible="false" top="0" maintainAspectRatio="true"  />         
</s:Group>
```

The only other part is in the main application you must specify a maxWidth and maxHeight for the custom component.

```
<components.myCustomImageGroup id="cig" maxWidth="500" maxHeight="400" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably approach this like so:

```
<s:Group ... creationComplete="parentingGroupCreationCompleteListener()">
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    private function parentingGroupCreationCompleteListener():void
    {
        this.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, parentingGroupResizeListener);
    }

    private function parentingGroupResizeListener(e:ResizeEvent):void
    {
        updateImageDimensionsAndPosition(this.width, this.height);
    }

    private function updateImageDimensionsAndPosition(w:Number, h:Number):void
    {
        imgA.width = w;
        imgA.height = h;

        // If you want to center the image, uncomment the following
        //imgA.x = s.width/2 - imgA.width/2;
        //imgA.y = s.height/2 - imgA.height/2;

    }

    override public function updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number):void
    {
        updateImageDimensionsAndPosition(w,h);
        super.updateDisplayList(w,h);
    }

]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:Group>
```

Hope that's useful.

Comment: That seems to partially work.  There are 2 issues I have now.
1. The image grows with the parent container fine, but will not shrink.
2. Centering the image that way won't work as the width of imgA and the parent container are the same.

Any thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks J

Answer (score 1):

you have written this line.

```
var aspect:Number = imgA.width / imgA.height;
```

use this line instead of previous line.

```
var aspect:Number = imgA.contentWidth / imgA.contentHeight;
```